# Elementary OS major upgrade purchases

Tags: updates

I just purchased elementary os so I can try it out and I see that it is getting ready for a major upgrade this year. Do you pay for each major upgrade or do you receive the upgrade automatically when it is released? I'm new to the linux world and trying to figure out how upgrades work once I commit to an operating system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The software is free and open-source, donations are optional.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, it is unknown whether installation of version 6 will require a full re-install when it is released. Keep an eye on the [elementary Blog](https://blog.elementary.io)

Answer (score 0):

Got it, thank you. I was just wondering if you need to re-install the major software update similar to how you originally install the os vs through their built in software interface from within the os. I should have been more clear about that. Appreciate your response!